# Javafx Memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a phone book application. On start the application loads every thing to a trie and a list, put them in a list view on the right hand side of the app and there is some textfields and imageview on the left hand side so when  new selection is made in the list, those info fields are updated with new contact details.

Like that:
[image]

So after the load up and viewing everything nothing is really created again and I dont keep reference to anything.

When new contact selected I get his data and it is replaced with the previous data in fields even the image I only keep reference to the imag location when contact is selected I go load a new image and put it in the image view :

```
public void createImage(String url, double loadWidth, double loadHeight, Point2D viewPortStart)
    {
        notifier.setVisible(false);
        //load the image
        try{
            File file = new File(url);
            if(!file.exists())
                throw new Exception();

            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toString(),loadWidth,loadHeight,true,true);

            //set dragging fields
            this.viewPortStart.x = viewPortStart.getX();
            this.viewPortStart.y = viewPortStart.getY();
            moved.x = viewPortStart.getX();
            moved.y = viewPortStart.getY();

            //put image to view
            view.setImage(image);

            //update viewport
            view.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(viewPortStart.getX(),viewPortStart.getY(),SIZE,SIZE));

            //notify that this component contains a photo now
            containsPhoto.setValue(true);
            notifier.setVisible(false);
            validProperty().setValue(true);
            imageLocation = url;
            imageHeight = loadHeight;
            imageWidth = loadWidth;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            createEmptyImage();
            showImageLoadError(url == null ? "unknown path":url);
        }
    }
```

So I started profiling this with Yourkit. On application start it uses 50mb in yourkit and 120mb in task manager. Then I use the keyboard to go down the whole list of cantacts after that I force a garbage collection and the new used memory is 400mb on task manager and 120 mb on yourkit?!!!

See below the selected blue line indicate the time where I forced a grabage collection.
[image]

it indicates a 120mb usage but when I take a snapshot I only see a 15 mb retained objects?

[image]

Any one can help to clarify this? Or how can I track the leak here?

Comment: http://forums.yourkit.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3903 seems similar

Comment: You seem to be confused between used memory and allocated memory.

Comment: so this mean i have 120mb allocated memory where there is only 15 mb used in it? does this means memory leaks the allocated space? or it is normal to have this? I am just amazed how this simple app can consume up to 400mb!!

Answer (score 1):

Allocated memory is the memory the JVM has to play with, while used memory is the amount actually used at any given time. You can specify min and max for the allocated memory when the JVM starts. Initially the JVM will allocate the minimum value, or more if your application needs it. If over time the used memory is far below the allocated memory, the latter will go down as well. The task manager in Windows normally only reports the allocated memory.

If an application is not used, it is normal to see a "saw tooth" pattern where used memory grows until next garbage collection, then goes down to the level it was at just after the previous gc. This is normal and does not signify a memory leak.

If, however, the used memory amount after each gc is increasing over time, it is an indication of a memory leak.